# Why we don't declare variables in class when using self keyword

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I've got structed in self keyword.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self,gender):
        self.gender=gender
John=Person("Male")
Richa=Person("Female")
print(f"John is {John.gender} and Richa is {Richa.gender}")
```

Why don't we declare the variable gender in the class Person, where self.gender is pointing ?
Like in any other programming languages we used the `this` keyword

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
  
  Person(string gender)
  {
  this->gender=gender;
  }
};
int main()
{
    Person john("Male");
    cout<<john.gender;
    return 0;
}
```

In this we've declared gender variable in class also and `this->gender` is pointing to something which can be understood, but not in Python.

I know I am mixing two programming languages but I want to understand this.

Comment: Python is a dynamic programming language, and it *doesn't have variable delcarations*, not like Java. It has type hints, but those aren't exactly the same thing

Comment: "Like in anyother programming languages we used this keyword" No, not in any other programming language. C++ is an example, but not all languages are C++, C#, and Java. Also note, `self` is *not a keyword*. In Python, that is merely a convention. Instancevs are passed to methods as the *first positional argument*, which you *can* name anything you want (although, you should use `self` if you want to write idiomatic code)

Comment: FWIW, your example is NOT how members are declared in C++. C++ is a typed language so the compiler needs to know the type of each variable at compile time. Python is a scripting language so decides any types at runtime. But I have some sympathy, having made the C++ -> Python transition. The ability for a Python class to create ‘instance variables’ pretty much anywhere took some getting used to.

Comment: @DS_London Python is a typed language. It just doesn't use static, nominal typing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I take your point.

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: explanation of self here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `class Person` you just define an skeleton or a template but every time you make an instance of `Person` class you're actually calling the `__init__` function of the class (the constructor).
So what actually brings a `Person` instance to life is the `__init__` function and it is best practice to define person's attributes there.
Here `self` works just like `this` and it refers to the current instance of the class not the class template itself.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects):

> Data attributes correspond to “instance variables” in Smalltalk, and to “data members” in C++. Data attributes need not be declared; like local variables, they spring into existence when they are first assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples:

```
self.gender
```

has the same use as:

```
this->gender
```

so it is just you have to get used to "replace" "this->" by "self."
and you can access an instance variable value.

The "only strange thing" is that you have to add "self" as the first parameter of each class method also.